# Wrong ILP solution with LPSolve (simple example)

Tags: optimization, problem-solving, integer-programming, discrete-optimization

I added the following example into LPSolve and found a strange issue. I don't want `S1` and `S2` to overlap within certain margins. For this I've added some binary variables to reduce a large term to be zero or something large, but nothing in between.

However, the solver now sets both `S` to 0, even though it also sets `B2` to zero. In my mind this contradicts line C, as it would result in `0 >= 1`.

Any ideas why I'm getting this wrong solution?

```
min: S1+S2;

A: S1 - S2 + 11442401 B1 >= 4;
B: S1 - S2 + 11442401 B1 < 11442405;
C: S2 - S1 + 11442401 B2 >= 1;
D: S2 - S1 + 11442401 B2 < 11442402;
E: B2 + B1 = 1;

bin B1;
bin B2;
```

If I use a 2 instead on a one in line C as a bound, I get the correct result.

Comment: It is obvious, that $S_1=S_2=B_2=0;...$ is not a solution. But what solution do you get ? And what is the given solution ?

Comment: The solver gave me S1, S2, B2 = 0 and B1 = 1, which is wrong. However when I reduce the size of the large numbers the solver works fine, so I seems to be some rounding issue. Any idea which parameter I have to increase? I guess it does some internal calculation so that 0 * 11442401 results in something larger than zero.

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to a too large feasibility tolerance compared to your big-M values.
Try decreasing one of these paramaters:

- epsb :  set minimum tolerance for the RHS See set_epsb
- epsel :  set tolerance for rounding values to zero See set_epsel

(Reference: http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/lp_solve.htm)

P.S.: the strict "<" seems strange to me, did you mean "<="?